# Java EclipseLink - PrivateOwned collection not deleting on clear

Tags: java, annotations, persistence, eclipselink

I have what I would think is a fairly typical setup in EclipseLink, although admittedly I am a bit new to EclipseLink. I've worked with Persistence and Hibernate a bit, but usually through some convenience wrappers and such and not as directly as I am here. Persisted class A contains a list of persisted class B. It's annotated as follows:

```
public class A {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = B.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fieldA")
    @PrivateOwned
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private List<B> bItems;
}

public class B {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOIN_COL")
    private A aItem;
}
```

The creation and editing of these objects is working just fine. When an object A is deleted, it cascades as it should and any B objects tied to it are cleared out as well. The issue I'm hitting is trying to clear B objects from A directly. Normally this is done via a UI with some intermediary DTO objects between. That's working fine. However, I have some backend code that needs to clear out all of Object B directly from the domain object A in certain circumstances. It seems that using:

```
itemA.getBItems().clear();
```

is not working. I would think that this should be picked up by the EntityManager (which is done with a simple `entityManager.persist(objectA)` in a service class), but it's not clearing the associated B objects in the database. Is that simply the nature of the way I'm doing it or even the way the ArrayList class implements clear() (I'd try some other methods, but the nature of the beast in this case makes it difficult and time-consuming to properly test), or do I need to get a bit more fine grained on how I do this? Perhaps my annotations are a bit off? Or perhaps I'm doing things correctly but need to add a convenience method to the service class that clears out the B objects via the EntityManager and evicts any relevant caches?

Comment: If it is unmanaged, changes won't be picked up and you are required to call merge on it.  You mention entityManager.persist(objectA), but shouldn't it be a entityManager.merge(objectA) call?  persist is only for new objects, and should result in an exception on an unmanaged entity (sometimes on flush or commit).

Comment: I am running into this same issue. Using openjpa implementation of the JPA2.0 spec the above code works fine. When using eclipselink implementation of the JPA2.1 spec I run into the same issue as reported above. In my case the code is running in a bean which is managed, so I'm unsure why these objects still remain in the db after clearing them. Did you ever figure this out?